# SQL Compact lock timeout on __SysObjects

Tags: locking, timeout, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL Compact 3.5 SP2. My application is multi-threaded, but it does not share connections across threads. Instead, I use a custom object pool to ensure that each thread gets its own connection. That said, it's possible that a connection might be re-used on different threads at different times... in other words, I'm assuming that the connections don't have thread affinity. Also, not sure if it matters, but I'm using Entity Framework in .NET 3.5 SP1.

Anyway, when I've got high load situations (8+ threads), I'm getting lock timeout exceptions (regardless of the length of the timeout setting), and the exception always says the lock was on the __SysObjects table.

I'm not doing any DDL, so I don't understand why I would get locking timeouts on that table. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somewhat resolved this issue by making sure that my connections were closed after each use (as opposed to pooling the open connections), but if I let the code run for a long period of time I started getting OutOfMemoryException and AccessViolation exceptions.

This smells like the SqlCeConnection class has some kind of thread affinity dependency. Either that, or it has a memory leak of some kind.

At any rate, I've given up on trying to pool these objects.

EDIT: This actually appears to be an issued address by Cummulative Update 2. Since updating my references to the new libs, I haven't seen this problem. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983516